# Using two CSS property in JQUERY code

Tags: jquery, css

Imagine I clicked the button, then the confirmation will show. But using `Visibility` property. Then I have jquery code having a two css property inside in jquery code.

This is the code:

```
$("#success").css({"visibility": "visible"}).delay(3000).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
```

Please tell me what's the correct syntax for this, I don't want to use the show hide property. Thankyou

Comment: Could you explain what is it that you are trying to get?

Comment: I already updated my code in my question.

Comment: @Abinthaha I want to have an two css property inside jquery code

Comment: Can you try to toggle a class, so that there won't be css properties inside jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it `visible` instantly and let it `fadeOut()` after `delay()`:

```js
$("#success").click(function() {
  $("#conf").css('visibility', 'visible').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#conf {visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="success">Confirm</button>
<span id="conf">Confirmed</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate the `visibility` property. Assuming you want the element to fade in/out whilst retaining it's space in the DOM then you could use the `opacity` CSS property instead.

To achieve this you can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` while setting `transition` on that applied class. Also note that you'll need to work with the animation queue manually as the class amending methods do not use it by default. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("#success").addClass('visible').delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('visible').dequeue();
  });
});
```

```css
#success {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#success.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="success">Lorem ipsum</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('#success').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` work with the `display` property of CSS, not `visibility`. The OP specifically states they do not want to do this.